# Experiences with Intel XDK and Cordova CLI: What is better?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, intel-xdk

I'm currently planning a cordova app targeting Android, iOS and Windows Phone 8.1. No I'm wondering on which build workflow I should rely on. On the one hand there's builind via the command line interface (CLI) of cordova, on the other one there's Intel XDK (for Linux in my case).

Is thre anyone who has experiences with one or both types and could share his/her knowledge with the community? Are there any bottlenecks with Intel XDK? Is it usable or not worth a try. Is it hard to production-build the app for those 3 platforms on myself (at least android doesn't seem too hard)?

Bye The_Unknown

Comment: If you want to develop for those 3 platforms, you need windows 8 for WP8 apps and mac os 10.9 for iOS apps. If you don't have windows and mac, you can use phonegap build service, but then you have to use the phonegap CLI or upload your code to github. I'm not sure if intel XDK supports phonegap or just cordova.

Comment: PhoneGap is an Adobe trademark, it uses Cordova under the hood, just like the Intel XDK. All of these build Cordova apps: PhoneGap Build, Cordova CLI, PhoneGap CLI and Intel XDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question will be flagged shortly, I am sure. :-)

The XDK is pretty good, but is possibly overambitious in some areas. I'd like to see them dump the AppDesigner (GUI builder) portion of it, and focus all efforts on the remainder of the toolset. It is integrated with Crosswalk for Android so it is quite slick for that platform. There is a brand new release of the XDK out in the past couple of days. Their new cloud build service is not building for WP8 right now, so you would need to use the legacy service (which is accessible within the IDE). As a general aside, the team supporting it at Intel is remarkably active on their support forums and appear highly responsive when I've seen production-related issues arise.

A quick comment I would make is that the more your app may depend on "non-core" Phonegap plugins (i.e. not the ones that are part of the Cordova/Phonegap base like Camera or Notification) the more you will be pushed into building the apps for testing rather than doing emulated or on-device debugging in one of the harnesses.

Personally I am taking the approach of using the XDK, but minimizing my reliance on the various XDK plugins when a standard Cordova plugin will work. I figure this way if I need to switch to Cordova or Phonegap Build at some point, the migration should be fairly painless (or at least easy to determine needed changes), while in the meantime I do get some of the niceties the XDK provides.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Made it clear a bit more. But one thing I keep asking myself: How do I debug with a cloud based build service? What if something is wrong with the code but I don't know where to look just from staring at the app the cloud build service produced?

Comment: @barry-johnson make's some good recommendations regarding XDK plugins versus Cordova plugins -- use the Cordova plugins whenever possible.

The XDK tries to be compatible with Cordova CLI as much as possible, you can actually use both and we are adding features to make the plugins more transparent (where the plugin code is more readily available) in order to improve debugging and customization. That will be a while.

Regarding App Designer, that is totally optional. You are not required to use AD to create your UI. Use whatever you like.

p.s. I work for Intel on the XDK team.

Comment: @xmnboy - Thanks. And I recognize your handle - I stalked you on Github while looking for example code. LOL I do understand App Designer is optional, but I also recognize that it is fairly complex, particularly with its multi-framework support. I view doing it right as a quagmire with limited overall utility over the app lifecycle, as I think for most apps that make it to production - even in a private/limited case, hand coding will be necessary. OTOH, there are already strong areas of the XDK that could be made compelling and a couple of good greenfield feature opps with better bang for $.

Answer (score -1):

I have worked with Intel XDK before but i haven't taken a look into it for over half a year so i don't know what updates have been applied to it recently. I have only worked with cordova for an hour or so and my experience with it until then wasn't great to say the least.

In my opinion it's still better to create native platform apps for each platform. It will cost more time and requires more knowledge, but it will give the users all the UX they are used to from their own platform. This will make a more unified experience for users and they will appreciate it. And ofcourse there are endless amounts of tutorials online.

Hope my answer helped you a little

Comment: I don't think this helps, @The_Unknown is decided to develop hybrid apps, he wants to choose an IDE

Comment: Totally right. Besides that, the decision wasn't mine. I'd also rather build native apps, but it's always a trade-off between cost and use.